# Gestionar el repositorio de una API al crear una nueva versión de esta

Tags: api, git

Si tengo que versionar una API porque se ha decidido que todos los nuevos cambios van a ir a nueva versión. Como se maneja el código? hablo del repositorio
Se me ocurren dos opciones, tag o fork
Puedo 'taguear' la version actual como V1 y seguir con el código ahí mismo (siempre tendré el código de la V1 si hace falta, pero en caso de tener que corregir algo de la V1 no se me complicaría?)
O 'forkear' el código y llevarlo la nueva versión en otro repositorio diferente?
Cual sería la mejor forma de realizar esto?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones y seguramente termine cerrada. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]. Respecto al tema de versionado, te comparto las especificaciones sobre el [versionado semántico](https://semver.org/)

Comment: @AndresGardiol Tienes razón, sigo leyendo y veo que es una cuestión mas de preferencias personales, me adelante en preguntar voy a revisar el tema de versionado semantico, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es una subida de versión estrictamente hablando seria el tag de versión. Aunque como te explica Andrés en su comentario, esto va en opiniones personales.

Al final el problema de lanzar la versión en un repositorio diferente es que puedes perder el histórico de cambios anteriores (porque tu Init Commit seria la versión 1.0 al completo) mientras que si lo mantienes en el mismo repositorio, si haces muchisimas versiones acabaras un poco perdido.

La mejor solución depende del proyecto en particular, del gusto del desarrollador y de lo grandes que sean los cambios que vayas a aplicar. Pero si no es un cambio absoluto y total (cambio de lenguaje o implementación de nuevo framework por ejemplo) yo diría que TAG es mejor

Comment: Si, me parece mas correcto usar TAG en este caso.